# raw bits (from a .bin file or a hardware) to bitmap pixel in c++

Tags: c++, bitmap, binary, bit

I have seen and understood example of how to manipulate with the .bmp images themselves. My next step is to convert the raw bits that I am getting from my

1. FPGA device
2. binary file (.bin file)

and convert them to pixels so that I can make the bitmap from it.

I try the following function, CreateBitmap() in C++ but cannot succeed since it seems it only deals with pixels.
thanks

Comment: Can you give more details, pls? After convert them to pixels, how is ur data, etc.

Comment: If O understand your question right, you make mistake in understanding what I say, I mean I need to convert my data in bits to pixel format.
after converting to pixel, then I want to make the .bmp image.

Comment: so Now for example my raw data is 0b"0100111010110111"....I want to make pixel out of it.

Comment: ok but each pixel has got some attributes, RGB or something. How do u parse your raw data? Or ur bitmap will be just Black and White bitmap? I guess you can give more detail about ur question

Answer (score 0):

you can look at this site for understand bitmap architecture and you can find how to convert raw data to bitmap or bitmap to raw data

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format